# What is the recommended dual GPU configuration on a dual CPU machine?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, sli, crossfire, dual-gpu

So there are about 4 PCIE in a motherboard, two of these are connected on each CPU, such as PCIE 1 and 2 is connected on CPU1 and PCIE 3 and 4 is connected to CPU2. Possible configurations were

1. GPU1 on PCIE1, GPU2 on PCIE2
2. GPU1 on PCIE1, GPU2 on PCIE3

Notice on (1) all GPU connected to PCIE are into only 1 CPU, while one (2), one GPU is connected on CPU1 and the other is connected on CPU2. The GPUs are connected by either SLI or CrossFire.

Which configuration for a DUAL GPU be faster? Benchmarks would also be appreciated.

Comment: Are you going to use those two GP as a couple (e.g. SLI or Crossfire?). Then having them in the same CPU and same PCI-e lanes might be faster. If you just want to do calculations on them then the opposite might be faster.

Comment: Could there be any test on that?

Comment: There probably is, but I no longer have dual-CPU setups. My last was a dual AMD 2200+ (single core era).

Comment: I see, I might probably set up my GPU based on choice no. 1